# Message and Label Difference? (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, label

What I don't understand is what is the difference between a **message and a label**. They look so much similar. Is there anyone who can clarify this?

I am not talking about the **message box widget**. I just had a doubt about the **message and label widget**

The code syntax is something like this -

```
M1 = Message(root,options...)
L1 = Label(root,options...)
```

They look so similar as a output.

Comment: From `tkinter/__init__.py` (`tkinter`'s source code): "*Message widget to display multiline text. Obsolete since Label does it too.*"

Comment: @TheLizzard: I think the tkinter source code is incorrect. It's not obsolete, it's just different and not as commonly used as a Label.

Comment: @BryanOakley Do you want to file a bug report? Also with a bit of string manipulation aren't you able to do everything that `Message` does with a `Label`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the [canonical description](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/message.htm#M9) of the message widget:

> A message is a widget that displays a textual string. **A message widget has three special features that differentiate it from a label widget.** First, it breaks up its string into lines in order to produce a given aspect ratio for the window. The line breaks are chosen at word boundaries wherever possible (if not even a single word would fit on a line, then the word will be split across lines). Newline characters in the string will force line breaks; they can be used, for example, to leave blank lines in the display.

> The second feature of a message widget is justification. The text may be displayed left-justified (each line starts at the left side of the window), centered on a line-by-line basis, or right-justified (each line ends at the right side of the window).

> The third feature of a message widget is that it handles control characters and non-printing characters specially. Tab characters are replaced with enough blank space to line up on the next 8-character boundary. Newlines cause line breaks. Other control characters (ASCII code less than 0x20) and characters not defined in the font are displayed as a four-character sequence \xhh where hh is the two-digit hexadecimal number corresponding to the character. In the unusual case where the font does not contain all of the characters in “0123456789abcdef\x” then control characters and undefined characters are not displayed at all.