# How to not overflow text from ScrolledText in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, chatbot, tkinter-scrolledtext

I am just learning Tkinter and Python. I am trying to design a chatbot. While designing the chatbot I wrote a response which is now overflowing.
Obviously here it can be broken down using '\n' but I will be fetching long responses from json file or a user can send long inquires.
So, What I can do so that text remain in the window and does not overflow?

Any further suggestion is always welcome.

Here is my [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foeTE.jpg).

Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext as ScrolledText


def send():
    ChatLog.tag_configure('tag-left', justify='left')
    ChatLog.tag_configure('tag-right', justify='right')
    ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)

    frame1 = Frame(ChatLog, bg="#d0ffff")
    Label(
        frame1,
        text="You: What you can do?",
        font=(
            "Arial",
            11),
        bg="#d0ffff").grid(
            row=0,
            column=0,
            sticky="w",
            padx=5,
        pady=5)
    Label(
        frame1,
        text=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"),
        font=(
            "Arial",
            7),
        bg="#d0ffff").grid(
            row=1,
            column=0,
        sticky="e")

    frame2 = Frame(ChatLog, bg="#ffffd0")
    Label(
        frame2,
        text="Bot: I can guide you through Adverse drug reaction list, Blood pressure tracking, Hospitals and Pharmacies",
        font=(
            "Arial",
            11),
        bg="#ffffd0").grid(
            row=0,
            column=0,
            sticky="w",
            padx=5,
        pady=5)
    Label(
        frame2,
        text=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"),
        font=(
            "Arial",
            7),
        bg="#ffffd0").grid(
            row=1,
            column=0,
        sticky="e")

    ChatLog.insert('end', '\n ')
    ChatLog.window_create('end', window=frame1)
    ChatLog.tag_add("tag-right", "end-1c linestart", "end-1c lineend")
    ChatLog.insert('end', '\n ')
    ChatLog.window_create('end', window=frame2)
    ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)


base = Tk()
base.title("Chatbot")
base.geometry("400x500")
base.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
base.configure(bg='white')

ChatLog = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(
    base,
    bd=0,
    bg="white",
    height="8",
    width="50",
    font="Arial")
ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)

SendButton = Button(
    base,
    font=(
        "Verdana",
        12,
        'bold'),
    text="Send",
    width="8",
    height=5,
    bd=0,
    bg="#fd94b4",
    activebackground="#ff467e",
    fg='#ffffff',
    command=send)

EntryBox = Text(base, bd=0, bg="white", width="29", height="5", font="Arial")


ChatLog.place(x=6, y=6, height=386, width=383)
EntryBox.place(x=6, y=401, height=90, width=265)
SendButton.place(x=275, y=401, height=90)

base.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should be able to pass in a `wraplength` parameter (in pixels, I think) when creating your `Label`s.

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible to configure the label so that it will wrap, this is one of the rare cases where a `Message` widget might be more appropriate since it automatically supports wrapping and justification.

For more information about how Label and Message widgets differ, see [Message and Label Difference? (tkinter)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67920384/7432)

Example:

```
Message(
    frame2,
    text="Bot: I can guide you through Adverse drug reaction list, Blood pressure tracking, Hospitals and Pharmacies",
    font=(
        "Arial",
        11),
    bg="#ffffd0").grid(
        row=0,
        column=0,
        sticky="w",
        padx=5,
    pady=5)
```

[image: screenshot]